# How can I adjust the row heights in a ListView so they take up the remaining space?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a ListView which can have 2-4 rows in it. I want the rows to change their height so they are even, and fill up the remaining space in the LinearLayout.

This is a snippet of what I have:

**activity_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/quiz_question_box"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:id="@+id/question_text_view"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/options_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:padding="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_content_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20sp">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Gives me this:**

[image]

I've tried setting the weight of pretty much everything I can think of, including the LinearLayout in the row_layout.xml with the hope that the rows would be distributed evenly, but no luck. I've also tried setting the parameters of the view in the getView method of my Adapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    if((position % 2 == 1) && (position != getNumberOfItemsInList())){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quiz_middle_answer_bordered_light);
    } else if ((position % 2 == 1) && (position == getNumberOfItemsInList()))  {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quiz_bottom_answer_rounded_light);
    } else if ((position % 2 == 0) && (position != getNumberOfItemsInList())){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quiz_middle_answer_bordered_dark);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.quiz_bottom_answer_rounded_dark);
    }
    return  view;
}
```

But that hasn't worked either. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your text views you declared the height to be wrap context that means they'll take the minnimal height and that's normally what you want to do.
However you want them to fill the entire space so what you should do is to set the height to match parent.
 Now to prevent one of them to occupy the full object and therefore pushing the other off the screen you need to assign android:weight to them

Comment: What element am I setting? The LinearLayout in the row file? The TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do,

1) Find the screen height in dp

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

find half the screen height and pass this value to the list adapter

2) Divide this value by item count. You can call the method `getItemCount()`

Now we have the height of each list view child. Now on `getView()` you can the height of linear layout with this value.

Answer (score 0):

Assign weigths to the rows that way they can take as much size as you want independent of your device screen